# Duck-typing an element in XSLT with XSD

Tags: xslt, xsd, duck-typing

I'm creating a function in XSL which accepts an XML element as a parameter. I have certain expectations from this XML element: for example, it must have a `<name>` subelement and an `<id>` subelement. So either of the following two elements are acceptable:

```
 <person>
   <id>1234</id>
   <age>16</age>
   <address><city>NYC</city><state>NY</state></address>
   <name>J. Random</name>
 </person>

 <company corp="false">
   <name>ACME, Inc.</name>
   <founded>1973</founded>
    .
    .
    .
   <id>6785</id>
 </company>
```

Note that I don't care about the element name, the order in which `<name>` and `<id>` appear, and any other sub-elements (or attributes) the element has.

Can I express this requirement in XSD, and use it for the `as` attribute of an `<xsl:param>`?

Answer (score 1):

You could define a complex type in XSD whose only requirements are that the content includes a name and an id element, but I'm not sure this would be a very useful thing to do; I think you would be using the type system in a way it wasn't intended to be used and you would probably end up finding it frustrating, though I don't know exactly where you would hit difficulties.